# How should I restore my files after I get the following output

Tags: kali-linux, data-recovery

I am trying to recover all my deleted folders and files The first step I took was

```
Inode  Owner  Mode    Size      Blocks   Time deleted
8391823      0 120777      3      1/     2 Wed Jul  6 00:21:52 2016
6816215      0 120777      3      1/     2 Tue Aug 30 22:23:12 2016
6816241      0 120777      3      1/     2 Tue Aug 30 22:23:12 2016
6816248      0 120777      2      1/     2 Tue Aug 30 22:23:12 2016
6816268      0 120777      2      1/     2 Tue Aug 30 22:23:12 2016
6816336      0 120777      2      1/     2 Tue Aug 30 22:23:12 2016
6816338      0 120777      2      1/     2 Tue Aug 30 22:23:12 2016
6816340      0 120777      2      1/     2 Tue Aug 30 22:23:12 2016
8 deleted inodes found.


root@kali:~# df /root
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5      192360020 12389648 170176020   7% /
root@kali:~# debugfs -w /dev/sda5
debugfs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
debugfs:  lsdel
debugfs:  logdump -i <8391823>
Inode 8391823 is at group 1024, block 33554564, offset 1792
Journal starts at block 24819, transaction 1055643
No magic number at block 25323: end of journal.
debugfs:  logdump -i <6816215>
Inode 6816215 is at group 832, block 27263022, offset 2816
Journal starts at block 24819, transaction 1055643
No magic number at block 25628: end of journal.
debugfs:  logdump -i <6816241>
Inode 6816241 is at group 832, block 27263023, offset 2048
Journal starts at block 24819, transaction 1055643
No magic number at block 25696: end of journal.
debugfs:  logdump -i <6816248>
Inode 6816248 is at group 832, block 27263023, offset 2944
Journal starts at block 24819, transaction 1055643
........
```

What would be the next step for me to recover all my files and folders

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to try Testdisk as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes recover files with debugfs, but it's difficult. The file names and locations are lost, so you get content that isn't associated with a name. It can be difficult to distinguish between the latest version of a file and earlier version, though in principle you can tell from the deletion date.

Running debugfs to recover a deleted file when it's *just* been deleted can work. If you've accidentally deleted a file, remount the filesystem read-only immediately. If you've deleted a lot of files, the process doesn't scale. If you've written to the filesystem since the deletion, the chances of recovering the deleted files shrink quickly.

To recover “all [your] deleted folders and files”, running debugfs is likely to be a waste of time. Restore from backups.

If you don't have backups, then sorry, but you're running that lesson the hard way. **Always have backups**.